ImageProps overwriting src and alt in NextImage
I have a wrapper called IllustrationWrapper that I am using in various components.
import Image, { ImageProps } from 'next/image';

const getImageUrl = (illustrationName: string) => {
  return `https://my-link.com/illustrations/${illustrationName}.svg`;
};

interface IllustrationProps extends ImageProps {
  illustrationName: string;
}

const IllustrationWrapper = ({ illustrationName, ...props }: IllustrationProps) => {
  const imageUrl = getImageUrl(illustrationName);
  const altText = imageUrl.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join(' ');

  return <Image {...props} src={imageUrl} alt={altText} unoptimized />;
};

export default IllustrationWrapper;

It is used for example in this component:

import Link from 'next/link';
import IllustrationWrapper from '~/common/components/IllustrationWrapper';


const DesktopNav = () => (
    <div className="flex-shrink basis-[14.125rem]">
      <Link href="/" className="inline-block" aria-label="To main site">
        <IllustrationWrapper illustrationName="LogoLight" width={80} height={28} />
      </Link>
    </div>
)

export default DesktopNav;

However, I get an error in DesktopNav saying Type '{ illustrationName: string; width: number; height: number; }' is missing the following properties from type 'IllustrationProps': src, alt
I guess that ImageProps from next is overwriting my src and alt tag in IllustrationWrapper. I do not want it to do it. How would I fix this?

You're defining the interface IllustrationProps as an object having all of the properties of ImageProps (including alt and src) and an additional illustrationName,
so you can define your interface as
interface IllustrationProps extends Omit<ImageProps, 'src' | 'alt'> {
  illustrationName: string;
}

which will exclude them
TS playground

What exactly does 'Omit' do?

@thegreenedition Constructs a type by picking all properties from Type and then removing Keys. Read more...
